# Xcode Instrument: What are the meaning of the columns when using Time Profiler?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, instruments

There are a lot of columns when using the Time Profiler, what is the meaning of the data in those columns?
When referring to Apple's doc, the Time Profiler in that document is quite old, and it doesn't tell much things.Is there an updated document?

columns includes:

```
Total Samples
Total Time
Running Time
Samples
Self
#Self
Total %
Self %
Parent %
Category %
Library
Symbol Path
Symbol Name
```

Comment: I think this is a great example of why it would be nice to start up a documentation section here on SO for Instruments.